# What type dataBase of I should use for bpms(nosql or sql)

Tags: database, business-process-management

I want to create a bpms.Now i no understand which of type dataBase   i should use for bpms nosql or sql.
bpms feature like :

1. Support big data
2. Fast query
3. My tables have relational.
4. Import and export data
5. mvc web app.

please help to me for select type database

Comment: Please provide more info about your use case. Choosing a DB requires lot more attributes.

Comment: Do you want to create BPMS (Business Process Management System) or simply some business process on custom DB? Have I understood you properly?